# Cocoapods on external harddrive

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I moved all my Xcode projects on to an external harddrive because my macbook was running low on space. Cocoapods have started to act weird now.

When I try to initialize a new podfile via terminal with pod init, I get the message:

```
[!] Multiple Xcode projects found, please specify one.
```

When I try to update or install an existing podfile, I get the message:

`[!] Could not automatically select an Xcode project. Specify one in your Podfile like so:`

```
project 'path/to/Project.xcodeproj'
```

Nothing seems to work. Is there any way I can get cocoapods to work with projects on an external harddrive?

The directories I have tried all have only one xcode project and I'm definitely in the right directory.

Comment: From the error, it seems that you have multiple Xcode projects in the folder from where you are lunching the `pod init`. Can you share the folder file list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Invisible copies of files prefixed with "._" are created on shared volumes and external disks that are formatted to work with both macOS and Windows. These invisible files are "resource fork" segments of files that are being created on the external volume."
- https://www.cnet.com/news/invisible-files-with-prefix-are-created-on-some-shared-volumes-and-external-disks/

These copies were preventing me from initializing or updating my podfiles.

Solution 1:
Go to the directory where you want to initialize a pod or the directory of the podfile you want to update in terminal. Type ls -a to list all files including hidden ones. Then type rm "._(NameOfFile)" to remove the copy. You should then be able to work with the podfile freely.

Solution 2 (Permanent):
Solution 2 is a permanent one but requires reformatting the external drive to Macintosh-Extended so the ._ file copies are not created.

The link above also gives some other ways to deal with ._ files without reformatting the external drive.